# Should I ask websites if I need to use their rss feed as data for my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, rss

Should I ask websites if I need to use their rss feed as data for my iPhone app?

I have seen several apps which use rss feed as their back end. Did they ask for permission from the websites whom they use as the source?
Most websites have a restriction on how many calls an app can make per second or per hour for an RSS feed. 
But if my app is distributed amongst several users, it is not really a single user who is calling for rss feed.

Also one idea I had was to cache the rss feed on some different server for some time, but then the users might not get the most latest feed. I will cache the downloaded app on the user's phone, but for how long would makes sense?

I don't wanna get sued for using RSS feed from websites, but asking every website for permission is too much.

Comment: "every website"... are you implementing a browser or a feed reader in which the user decides which feeds are being consumed?

Comment: It must be noted, however, that SO is not an appropriate place to get advice that even hits at being legal in nature. On a more human level, I suggest that if you app depends on just a handful of feeds... get in touch! Tell the folks who run the feed what you want to do and work with them. It's just common sense which seems to get lost in the pace of today's technology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most RSS feeds are available to the public to subscribe to, so there shouldn't be a problem if  your app is subscribing to them. If you were worried, however, you could contact the site (which I'm sure they'd appreciate), post a link to their site in your app (a nice gesture), or do as you said and cache the feed for as long as you think it could go without being updated.

I'm not 100% sure if this helps, but here are three articles on RSS licensing:

http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Syndication

http://wiki.creativecommons.org/RSS_1.0

http://wiki.creativecommons.org/RSS_2.0

Answer (score 0):

You don' need to to ask permission to consume an RSS feed - that's what it is implicitly for - content syndication.

However, you should check the copyright status of the content before you re-publish it.  Pretending the content is yours, not referencing it where required, or breaching terms of use of the content are actions that could land you up in hot water.

As for the refresh rate, if the refresh is triggered by the user, then I wouldn't worry about it - this is normal behaviour for an RSS client.  If you are automatically looking for updates to content, then setting an update a few minutes apart would be respectful.

However, if you are creating an app with wide distribution, and it is going to be hitting the same RSS feeds, then you almost certainly should cache the content on your own servers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, my app will let the user know what is the source of the information. I believe the RSS feeds themselves have a tag which tells about the copyright info..I might use that.

Comment: I was looking into caching the feed, but then a few sites actually deny us from caching their feeds. 
But there are also other sites whose RSS feed has a ttl field teling us on how long the time to live for the cache should be.
I could make my app stop polling for the feed until the ttl has expired.

Answer (score 0):

Just because the feed is available to the public does not mean that copyright laws don't apply. You have to get permission first.